# NestJS equivalent to express res.locals

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm building an API based on NestJS, I don't find how to store data from middleware and get them inside controllers.

With Express, I simply do:

```
// middleware
res.locals.foo = 'bar';
next();

// controller
user.foo = res.locals.foo; // 'bar'
```

With NestJS there isn't `locals` property to Response and I don't find equivalent.

Comment: Can't you create it `res.locals = { foo: "bar" }`?

Comment: Nope, I get `Property 'locals' does not exist on type 'Response'.`. And if I force types as any, it doesn't works

Comment: Same problem here 3 years later. Any sollution @PierreD?

Answer (score 3):

You can use locals in nestjs too. Like this

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
// other imports

@Injectable()
export class AuthMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    
    res.locals.token  = 'Hello i am locals';

    next(); 
  }
}
```

Controller

```
import { Controller, Get, Response } from '@nestjs/common';


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor() {}


  @Get('verify')
  async verifyDid(@Response() res): Promise<string> {
    console.log(res.locals);
    return res;
  }
}
```

**Applying Middleware**

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by not having a `locals` property. NestJS is a wrapper around either [Express](https://expressjs.com) or [Fastify](https://fastify.io), depending on your adapter, so in a middleware, where you have `req, res, next` you should be able to say `res.locals` or `req.locals` and then access that in the controller with `@Res()` or `@Req()` respectively. The only thing to watch out for is that if you use `@Res()` you lose some things like the ability to work with post-request interceptors and Exception Filters, as Nest can no longer guarantee a response will not already by sent.